# converting usernames to twitter ID returns the same ID number of dak

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using [this python script](https://digitalmedialab.ruc.dk/hostedservices/convert-twitter-handles-to-twitter-ids-python-script/) (after some tweaking to get it working) in Jupyter notebook to convert a list of twitter usernames into twitter ID numbers, but now I have an issue that i cant seem to find an answer for.

I had to change `u = api.get_user(myHandles[i])` to `u = api.get_user(screen_name='dak')` to get the code working (among other things) as suggested by answers to other questions on here, but this seems to have the result that, while it gives me a list of user ID's form the username list I input, the user ID's it gives me are all the same ID. It gives me '385203914' which is the user id for the account 'dak'. `Twitter-Ids [385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914]` for example.

I know absolutely nothing about python or any kind of coding besides very basic outdated HTML, so please explain how to fix this in the most basic way possible like you're talking to a toddler

I was told to add the script not sure which parts are relevant so I've included the whole script.

```
 # TAKE HANDLES AND CONVERT TO USERID COMMA SEPARATED
 
import tweepy
import csv
import time
 
# GLOBAL VARS
consumer_key = 'my k'
consumer_secret = 'my s'
access_token = 'my t'
access_token_secret = 'my ts'
 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
 
# SET OBJECT AND AUTHENTICATE
api = tweepy.API(auth)
 
# Prompt for usernames
print('Format input like this username1,username2,username3')
 
myHandles = input("Feed a comma separated list of user handles without the @-precursor ")
 
#Check for valid input
if myHandles:
    # Clear the input, prepare for lookup
    myHandles = myHandles.lower()
    myHandles = myHandles.replace('@','')
    myHandles = myHandles.replace(' ','')
    myHandles = myHandles.split(',')
    # Set a new list object
    myIdList = []
    # Loop trough the list of usernames
    for handle in myHandles:
        u = api.get_user(screen_name='dak')
        uid = u.id
        myIdList.append(uid)
        # print(i)
    # Print the lists
    print('Usernames',myHandles)
    print('Twitter-Ids',myIdList)
    #set a filename based on current time
    csvfilename = "csvoutput-"+time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%I%p")+".csv"
    print('We also outputted a CSV-file named '+csvfilename+' to your file parent directory')
    with open(csvfilename, 'w') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        wr.writerow(['username','twitter-id'])
        j = 0
        for handle in myHandles:
            writeline = myHandles[j],myIdList[j]
            wr.writerow(writeline)
            j = j+1
else:
    print('The input was empty')
```

when i input the list of usernames as it prompts, this is what it spits out

```
Format input like this username1,username2,username3
Feed a comma separated list of user handles without the @-precursor username,username,username,username,username,username,username,username,username
Usernames ['username', 'username', 'username', 'username', 'username', 'username', 'username', 'username', 'username']
Twitter-Ids [385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914, 385203914]
We also outputted a CSV-file named csvoutput-09-01-2022 14:02PM.csv to your file parent directory
```

(usernames were replaced to post here) as you can see it recognises the usernames and gives an equal number of ID's but it's all the ID for dak. If I input the list in the actual code it still gives me the prompt box to input usernames and when i do it gives the error

```
NotFound: 404 Not Found
50 - User not found.
```

Comment: Please share *your* relevant code in your post when you have a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Change...

```py
# Set a new list object
myIdList = []
i = 0
# Loop trough the list of usernames
for handle in myHandles:
    u = api.get_user(myHandles[i])
    uid = u.id
    myIdList.append(uid)
    i = i+1
```

to...

```py
# Set a new list object
myIdList = []
# Loop trough the list of usernames
for handle in myHandles:
    try:
        u = api.get_user(screen_name=handle)
        uid = u.id
        myIdList.append(uid)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I jsut tried that but it's given me

NotFound: 404 Not Found
50 - User not found.

Comment: That was an error in the console?
What type of error was it?
Try my edited version above.

Comment: tried the version above and got this error: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 25>()
     51 j = 0
     52 for handle in myHandles:
---> 53     writeline = myHandles[j],myIdList[j]
     54     wr.writerow(writeline)
     55     j = j+1

IndexError: list index out of range